# Sum of Independent Exponential variables with bounds

Tags: probability

I have two random variables, $x$ and $y$, that are independent and exponentially distributed with same parameter $\lambda$. Also, $a\leq x \leq b$ and $a\leq y \leq b$. I want to calculate the probability that their sum is less than a constant $c$:
\begin{equation}
Pr(X+Y<c|a\leq x \leq b \ \& \ a\leq y \leq b)
\end{equation}
This is equal with
\begin{equation}
\int_{a}^{c-a}\bigg(\int_{a}^{c-y}\lambda \exp(-\lambda y)\lambda \exp(-\lambda x)\ dx\bigg) dy=
\exp(-\lambda2a)-(1+\lambda c-\lambda 2a)\exp(-\lambda c)
\end{equation}
The results is correct when the upper limit in the integral is $c-y<b \  \Rightarrow c<b+a$, given that the maximum value of $x$ is $b$.
How can i calculate the same probability when $c-y>b \ \Rightarrow c>b+a$? Am i missing something? maybe it should be a general type without checking on the value of $c$?

Comment: The upper limit on the x integral is min(c-y,b) so y integral should be split into two integrals at y=c-b.

Comment: I am sorry but confused. The $y$ integral should be split into two integrals only when the upper limit of $x$ integral is $b$?

Comment: The original definition for $x$ has an upper limit of $b$, so when  $c-y\gt b$, the $x$ integral has to stop at $b$, otherwise use $c-y$.  so $y$ integral goes from $a$ to $c-b$ with $x$ stop at $b$ and $y$ from $c-b$ to $c-a$ with $x$ up to $c-y$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!Problem is solved.